# Timepicker jQuery auto select time when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, timepicker

I have been wondering if timepicker JS really compatible with android apps. It is because whenever i try to scroll the timepicker dropdown to find time like 23.00.00 which is on the bottom part of the dropdown, it's automatically set the time based on my finger position during scrolling and the dropdown gone. Then i need to click the time again and the same thing happen. Simple to say, i can't scroll down and up freely. In chrome yes because there is a mouse for scrolling, but not for android.

Is there a fix for this? I try to find the solution at the documentaries, but can't find something related to it.

My timepicker plugins and docs can be found here http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/

Comment: Did you find a solution? 
I have the same problem.